# Как сделать, чтобы переменная имела модификатор доступа `protected` (через автосвойства)?

Tags: c#

Когда мы в С# пишем вот такой код: (в каком-то классе)

```
public int Age { get; set; }
```

Насколько я понимаю, создается поле `Age` с модификатором `private` и два свойства `get` и `set` (с модификатором `public`)

А как сделать чтобы сама переменная имела модификатор доступа `protected` (через автосвойства) ?

Comment: оставляя в стороне "понимаю, создается поле Age с модификатором private", вопрос - зачем, если свойство уже `public`?

Comment: создается поле `Age` с модификатором `private` - да, но это так сказать в "скрытом режиме" (на уровне самой системы) вручную к ней доступа нету, как я знаю. То есть у неё доступ только для самого фреймворка но не для пользователей. А пользователи только через Getter `x = obj.Age`

Comment: Никак. Создавайте свойство и поле с нужным модификатором доступа вручную.

Comment: Можете написать протектек в любом месте. Как вместо public как и перед get или set. Чтоб сделать чтение или запись только с наследованных классов

Comment: Для начала, доступ к полю получить можно при помощи рефлексии. А что вы называете «переменной» — поле или свойство?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак. Вы не можете повлиять на работу компилятора. Более того, компилятор генерирует имя переменой случайным образом (единственное что четко оговаривается, это имя сгенерированной переменной не будет совпадать с существующими. Точка).
Как следствие доступ к переменной через с неизвестным именем... Оригинально)
Другое дело  - зачем может потребоваться доступ к ней?
Если вам требуется ограничить возможность для записи в автосвойство, можно использовать разные модификаторы.

```
public int Age { get; protected set; }
```

Мы получили публичный доступ на чтение, и запись в переменную только из классов наследников.